# How to customize the bottom bar in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am using a bottom bar in react native. How do I change the background color and make the active bar highlighted with a line at bottom as shown in the image?

Code -

```
export const InternalStacks = TabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },    
    Graph: { screen: GraphStack }
},{
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
            const { routeName } = navigation.state;
            switch(routeName){
                case 'Home':
                    iconName = require('../assets/icons/home.png');
                    iconNameFocused = require('../assets/icons/home.png');
                    break;
                case 'Graph':
                    iconName = require('../assets/icons/chart.png');
                    iconNameFocused = require('../assets/icons/chart.png');
                    break;
            }
            if(focused)
            return ( <Image style={{width: 20, height: 20, tintColor }} source={iconNameFocused} /> );
            else
            return ( <Image style={{width: 20, height: 20, tintColor }} source={iconName} /> );
        }
    }),
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#FBC530',
      inactiveTintColor: 'black',
    },
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
  });
```

Current design -
[image: Current Design]

Required Design -
[image: Required Design]

Tried with the below,

```
tabBarColor: '#E64A19',
backgroundColor: 'white',
```

but none of the worked. What is the better way to achieve the required design?

PS - Not worried about the icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have access to more `tabBarOptions` that might help. Here's how we style ours:

```
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: false,
      showIcon: true,
      activeTintColor: black,
      inactiveTintColor: gray,
      activeBackgroundColor: white,
      inactiveBackgroundColor: white,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: white,
      },
      tabStyle: {
        backgroundColor: white,
      },
    },
  }
```

as far as adding the bottom bar, you can toggle icons when they are `focused` like this:

```
  HOME: {
screen: HomeScreen,
navigationOptions: {
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => <HomeIcon focused={focused ? UnderlinedIcon : RegularIcon } />,
},
```

},

So maybe in one of the icons you add a line at the bottom and in the other you don't, and then they'll toggle when focused. Hope this helps!!